# Regex not start in zero if single digit

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I have a 5 textboxes that can input only numbers. I used `/^[1-9][0-9]+$/`, but what I need is if single digit is zero allow it.

[image]

Just like the picture above, I have 5 textboxes if 1 of the textbox is already equal the quantity the other textbox should allow a zero value. It can't be greater or lower than in quantity.

Comment: `/^([1-9][0-9]+|0)$/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a or condition

```
/^([1-9][0-9]*|0)$/
```

Comment: I tried that, but why it not allowed single digit? Like 1-9?

Comment: @user3318208 try `/^([1-9][0-9]*|0)$/`

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is:

```
/^\d+$/
```

Which will allow only a number of one or more digits.

Breakdown

`/`  start of regex
`^`  matches beginning of string
`\d` matches any digit
`+`  modifies the above to match one or more
`$`  matches the end of line
`/`  ends the regex